# define bool return value in c

Tags: c, return-value

I have one question for return value in C, I want to use "true" "false" to mark the condition for the function. But in C, return 0(false) means normal while return 1(true) means issues. So I define as true, 1 as false? Or I'd better just don't use the bool type to avoid this conflict?

Comment: "But in C, return 0(false) means normal while return 1(true) means issues." This isn't true. An `int` value returned by a function is whatever is appropriate to the situation. Don't redefine `true` and `false`.

Comment: That's usually for the exit of the process, not for your functions. The semantics of your functions should mean whatever you want them to mean. If you want a function to return a `bool` value, where `true` means success then that's what it should mean.

Comment: did you try this? #include <stdbool.h>

Comment: Note that it is considered poor and sloppy practice to use a plain booleans for error diagnostics. Professional API uses an enum with error codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be answered generally except that you should never "define" `0` as *true* and `1` as *false* since that is directly opposite of the Standard definition.

This is a case where you need to make a convention (decision) in your program and stick to it. There are at least two common solutions:

1. Return a `bool` where `true` means "success" and `false` means "failure".
2. Return an error code where `0` means no error and a non-zero value indicates the precise error which occurred. In this case, error codes may be specific for the function or common across the program. This is, by the way, the convention used in the Standard for the `main()` function, but there is not a strong practice dictating that this must be the case for other functions in the program as well.

There are other possibilities and the most important is to be consistent within the same category of functions (again, it is up to you to define what this means in your specific context).

If you choose to use a boolean return type, you should use the standard `bool` type:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool func()
{
   ...
   if(error) return false;  // Failure
   return true;  // Success
}
```

Comment: I have a question, how can I get the point positive in this question?

Comment: @KabiLink You mean the Stackoverflow "score"? - You cannot. It is up to the StackOverflow community to upvote/downvote questions and answers. Being a new user, or even experienced, it can be difficult to ask a question which will be considered a "good" question by the community. Following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should be a help. Anyway, regarding reputation, upvotes count 5 times as much as downvotes, so with the current votes, you still have positive reputation from this question :-)

Answer (score 1):

> That's usually for the exit of the process, not for your functions. The semantics of your functions should mean whatever you want them to mean. If you want a function to return a bool value, where true means success then that's what it should mean.

– Some programmer dude